# Does the PostGIS ST_AsMVTGeom function perform geometry simplification on the fly?

Tags: postgis, mapbox, vector-tiles

PostGIS now comes with a set of functions that allow to generate Mapbox Vector Tiles. Among them, the [`ST_AsMVTGeom`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsMVTGeom.html) allows to transform a geometry into the coordinate space of a tile (typically 4096x4096). Given a geometry containing consecutive points that falls onto the same coordinate after transformation, does the function perform simplication on the fly, or should the [`ST_Simplify`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Simplify.html) function be called beforehand?

Comment: Have you experimented to see if there was a difference or reviewed the source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such points get collapsed:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_AsMVTGeom(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 0 0.1, 1 1)'),
                              ST_MakeBox2D(ST_Point(0, 0), ST_Point(4096, 4096))));

         st_astext
---------------------------
 LINESTRING(0 4096,1 4095)
```

---

`LINESTRING(0 0, 0 0.1)` results in NULL, so I don't know why the documentation says that it "might collapse geometry into a lower dimension".